# How to lock a textBox in a C# windows app (prevent the user from typing anything) (NOT disabling it or making it unvisible)

Tags: c#, windows

:)
I'm making a C# typing program
and I want the user to be unable to type anything when he types a wrong letter, 
(I want the typing cursor to freeze at its position)
and when he presses backspace, only then he could resume his typing.

I have done this program in C++ by manipulating the ConsoleScreenCursorCoordinates, 
I tried to do the same in C# via manipulating textBox.Location but it didn't work.

In my program, there are 2 textBoxes, the sourceTextBox and the TypingTextBox
there is also a string variable called 'text' which will read from a textFile 
via a StreamReader and then I use this text variable to compare each element from it with what the user is typing.

I tired this:

```
bool madeMistake = false;
Point CurrentTypingPosition;
string whatIsWrittenBeforeTheMistake = "";

private void TypingTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
       if (!madeMistake)
       {
           if (e.KeyChar == text[typingIndex])
           {
               typingIndex++;
           }
           else if (e.KeyChar == backspace)
           {
               typingIndex--;
           }
           else
           {
               CurrentTypingPosition = TypingTextBox.Location;
               madeMistake = true;
               TypingTextBox.Text += " ";
               TypingTextBox.Location = CurrentTypingPosition;
               whatIsWrittenBeforeTheMistake = TypingTextBox.Text;
           }
       }
       else
       {

           if (e.KeyChar == backspace)
               madeMistake = false;
           else
           {
               TypingTextBox.Text = whatIsWrittenBeforeTheMistake;
               TypingTextBox.Location = CurrentTypingPosition;
           }
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another variation on this is to use the `Handled` property of the `KeyPress` event args, so you get something like:

```
void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{

    if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = false;
        return;
    }

    char expectedNext = expected[textBox1.SelectionStart];

    if (expectedNext != e.KeyChar)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input");
    }
}
```

Comment: As with the other methods, this all gets pretty weird when users use the arrow keys. Ultimately making a subclassed control as Steve suggests will be best.

Answer (score 2):

Another, more robust way around this is to create a custom TextBox, inheriting from TextBox itself. You will then be able to handle the KeyDown (PreviewKeyDown) events etc, and determine at each key stroke if something is wrong. If invalid, you can set the KeyEventArgs (e.Handled) to true, and prevent further user input (apart from backspace, which you can check for).

This avoids having to hook into Textbox events, which is desirable if using MVVM. And you can use this method if you require very fine grained control.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
    private void TypingTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        if (madeMistake)
            TypingTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: KeyPress still fires when the user types while ReadOnly is true.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to tweak this to use your StreamReader object in place of the character array I am using here, but this will work, but without requiring them to have to backspace.

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {            
        char[] charArr = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };  //spec out what is acceptable here

        foreach (char c in charArr)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar.CompareTo(c) > 0)
            {
                e.Handled = true;                    
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```